# How does caret split into CV folds? Can I avoid splitting randomly?

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret

As I understand when setting `trainControl(method="cv")` in the caret package, my training set is is split into K folds for cross validation. How is this splitting done? I assume it is randomized and stratified?

But the train set has been "upsampled" and if the split is randomized there will be a data leak over the train and test folds. (which lead to a overfit of course.) So, how can I avoid that the split is randomized and stratified? I want the folds to be made of consecutive samples. Can that be achieved?

Comment: Why not perform the train test split first and then CV over the train set? There will be no data leakage.

Comment: @Sada93 First split the cv folds and then "upsample", you mean? Yes, that would be the smartest thing to do, however this was not coded by me personally.